# Restore WHS2011 client backups from the cloud?

Tags: backup, windows-home-server, online-backup

Starting with a little background: I have a home server with Windows Home Server 2011 installed. I make backups of the data stored on my home client computers to the home server using WHS' built in backup functionality. The actual server data (some of the shares and the client backups) are backed up to an online backup service.

Now to the actual question: if my home server would crash, be destroyed in a house fire, etc. and I would reinstall it (possibly on different hardware), would I be able to use the client backup files restored from my online backup to restore a client computer or are the client backups somehow tied to the actual installion of WHS that made them?

EDIT: I'm using Carbonite, so there is no WHS add-in available.
EDIT2: Changed the phrasing to make the question clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I would help if you tell exactly what kind of online backup service you use. If you used [CloudBerry Backup for WHS](http://www.cloudberrylab.com/default.aspx?page=backup-vail), you would just needed to install the client on the new machine and download the data.

Thanks
Andy

Comment: I've added that information to the question. However, I'm not sure if that is relevant; does, for example, the Cloudberry add-in manage the backups of the client backups differently than it does other files it backups? I.e, if I restore my client backups from CloudBerry to a fresh installation of WHS, are the client backups modified in any way to work with the new installation of WHS? The clarify, the question I'm really looking for and answer for is whether these files _would_ have to be modified to work with the fresh installation.

Comment: It is relevant because every backup software manages files differently, most of them store your data in a proprietary data format and you can't get the data back without their client software. Another reason I asked is because you might need to follow certain instructions when restoring on a new computer to make sure you get your files and it differs from product to product.